# CSS how to have a <p> tag maintain its center within a image in a responsive website?

Tags: php, html, css, image

I have a responsive website with a number inside an image like this:

[image]

When I decrease the size of the browser the image will get smaller. My problem is that the number doesn't follow the image when the browser is decreasing. When the browser achieved its smallest possible size the number is in a different position from the image.
What should I do so that when I decrease the size of the browser, the number will follow the image as well as centering itself in the image?

Here is the PHP code:

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="twelve columns">


    <!-- Number inside the ribbon -->
    <div class="number">
    <p>

    <?php
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            if($row) {
                echo "{$row['Referrals']}";
        } 
    ?>

    </p>
    </div>
    <div class="redribbon"><img src="images/red.png" alt="redribbon"/></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS code

```
.number{
    float:left;
    background-position: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:200%;

    }

.number p{  
    position:absolute;
    top: 38%;
    left:57%;
    z-index:999;    
    }

.container .twelve.columns{
    height:150px;

    display:inline-block;
}

.redribbon{
    position:absolute;
    top:-5%;
    left:45%;
}

.redribbon img{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.twelve.columns                 { width: 100%; margin-left: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to rearrange your structure a bit, and you'll be able to accomplish this without media queries. Take a look at the fiddle below for a basic idea, the number in the middle is blue. You may need to create one media query to change the `font-size`.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8mbcae79/)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="twelve columns">
    <div class="redribbon">
        <div class="number">
            <p>767</p>
        </div>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVReT.png" alt="redribbon" />
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.redribbon{
    position:relative;
    width: 55%
}

.redribbon img {
  width: 100%;
}

.number {
  position: absolute;
  top: 46%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.number p {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: blue;
}

p{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use media query in your CSS to scale it down for different devices.
For more reference: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

**Examples:**

```
@media (max-width: 320px) {
    .number p{  
        font-size:120%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 321px) and and (max-device-width: 768px)  {
    .number p{  
        font-size:175%;
    }
}
```

and so on and on ~

Comment: This isn't true, please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear by the code you posted where you are doing the responsive stuff to scale the image down. So, I just focussed on keeping the number centered within the image.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ribbon</title>

    <style type="text/css">

        .container .twelve.columns{
            display: inline-block;
            }

        .redribbon{
            width: 284px;
            height: 207px;
            background: transparent url('DVReT.png') 50% 50% no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            }

        .number{
            width: 284px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 207px;
            font-size:200%;
            }

    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="twelve columns">

        <!-- Number inside the ribbon -->
        <div class="redribbon">
            <div class="number">273</div>
        </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Making the ribbon graphic a background image will make it easy to overlay the number onto it. The line-height of the `.redribbon` box should mirror the height of the `.number` box within the `@media` instructions that will make the image and number responsive to the browser window size.